# Solidification by the application of heat

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, phase-transition

When you add heat to a liquid (or a fluid), can it be solidified? If not, why in the world does an egg's stuffs become solid (or at least no more a liquid) when you 'boil' it in water?

Comment: I think the answer contains chemistry...

Comment: really, what is it then?

Answer (score 11):

A simple material will not undergo a liquid to solid transition as the temperature is raised. When you see this it means somthing more complicated than a simple phase transition is going on.

In the example of egg white, what you are seeing is [denaturation of the protein albumin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_%28biochemistry%29). The heat causes the protein to lose its tertiary structure then form cross links, and it's the cross linked structure that turns everything solid. You can tell it's not a phase transition because it isn't reversible if you lower the temperature gain.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation of egg turning solid which is a chemical change has well been explained by John. Interestingly, if we can trust the following article from [Physics World](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2004/sep/24/law-breaking-liquid-defies-the-rules), A liquid solution of α-cyclodextrine (αCD), water and 4-methylpyridine (4MP) turns from liquid to solid when heated to 45-75 degrees C. The interesting part to note here is the reversible nature of the physical change as explained in the linked article.

Comment: I'm sure there's a polysaccharide that forms a gel at high temperature but a liquid at low temperature. However I came across it back in the late 80s and I now can't remember the details. Googling hasn't helped, so I may simply be misremembering.