# Are there any liquid that becomes solid on heating under room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, states-of-matter

The title says it all. When I searched around, there are answers which involve extra steps like super cooling and then heating or exposing the liquid to high pressure. But I would like to know if there is any liquid that will transition to solid upon heating at room temperature. I'm especially looking for examples that can be done with stuff you find in your home and not require some crazy lab equipment.

Comment: Maybe egg white?

Comment: Near-room-temperature vulcanizing rubbers? Some epoxies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Solidification by the application of heat](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61769/solidification-by-the-application-of-heat)

Comment: @JohnRennie: That question is more specific to egg-white. But mine is more generic.

Comment: @JonCuster: Aren't epoxy resins semi-solids? The mixing of them produces heat and not consume, isn't it?